# How to rewrite this function problem in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

I have a project to rewrite the following function of a column of an Excel sheet in functional and understandable form, but unfortunately I do not understand the function. I could not make the tree of choice.

Here is the function.

> `=SI(EnvAReinstall="Yes";SI(LIGNE()>2;SI(ET(OU(GAUCHE($M1;3)<>"EnvATP1;$C1<>EnvATP2;$C1<>EnvATP3));DROITE($D1)="Y";$E1="PPCL"&EnvA;$AA1="No");"Yes";"No");"SDLC: To Reinstall in "&EnvA);"N/A")`

English function:

> `=IF(EnvAReinstall="Yes";IF(ROW()>2;IF(AND(OR(LEFT($M1;3)<>"EnvATP1;$C1<>EnvATP2;$C1<>EnvATP3));RIGHT($D1)="Y";$E1="PPCL"&EnvA;$AA1="No");"Yes";"No");"SDLC: To Reinstall in "&EnvA);"N/A")`

Comment: Can you give some sample data and output from the function so we have something to test against

Comment: And can you specify what part of it do you not understand?

Comment: Tnx for your answer the problem is i don't understand excel and how can i show you the output, second all the function i just understand just the first if... I want to do tree of choice to understand the function how. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are stuck with a complicated functions, just remember that it was always built from (a number of) simple functions. It is quite hard for us to comment, since there is no sample file/data that can help to clarify what does each condition meant.

However.. You may start with indentation (break-down) of the 1 line formula.. :

```
=IF(EnvAReinstall="Yes";

    IF(ROW()>2;

        IF(
            AND(

                OR( LEFT($M1;3)<>"<GI"
                    ; AND (LEFT($M1;3)="<GI"
                            ;$C1<>EnvATP1
                            ;$C1<>EnvATP2
                            ;$C1<>EnvATP3
                          )    

                   )

                ;RIGHT($D1)="Y"
                ;$E1="PPCL"&EnvA
                ;$AA1="No"

                )

        ;"Yes";"No")

    ;"SDLC: To Reinstall in "&EnvA)

;"N/A")
```

ADDITIONAL : from the comment.

```
=SI(EnvA<>"";
    SI(LIGNE()>2;
        SI(ESTNA(RECHERCHEV($A1;EnvARF80;2;FAUX));
            SI(
                OU(
                    ET($D1>=GAUCHE(EnvAMatA;3);$D1<=EnvAMatA);
                    ET($D1>=GAUCHE(EnvAMatB;3);$D1<=EnvAMatB)
                )
            ;"Matrix";"No")
        ;RECHERCHEV($A1;EnvARF80;2;FAUX))
    ;CONCATENER("Installed in ";EnvA;" in/on"))
;"N/A")
```

You just have to start the logic tracing from the innermost IF(), and you can always refer to excel help for the details of and(), or(), right(), left() & row() function.

Hope it helps (in the making of your tree of choice). ( :

Comment: thx Men finaly i solved my problem and i understand the function and i do it thx so much but if possible i give you another code to do it like the first

Comment: `=SI(EnvA<>"";SI(LIGNE()>2;SI(ESTNA(RECHERCHEV($A1;EnvARF80;2;FAUX));SI(OU(ET($D1>=GAUCHE(EnvAMatA;3);$D1<=EnvAMatA);ET($D1>=GAUCHE(EnvAMatB;3);$D1<=EnvAMatB));"Matrix";"No");RECHERCHEV($A1;EnvARF80;2;FAUX));CONCATENER("Installed in ";EnvA;" in/on"));"N/A")`

Comment: you may try to install notepad++ and paste the code there. Put your cursor on the 1st opening bracket, and it will highlight it's closing bracket. || The you press enter & tab to do the indentation.